How to implement verify-offchain-signature functionality in a Solana contract？
solana verify-offchain-signature --signer EBD44iUjdgc1nvq89zLHjVFJmDQjEFf75Zixn4j9sqL carl 2jtk9jzJ8gKLWiZWpNZAchst1gJmxbNiYb2TBVrcrbEQ9NU4pViMNVFmKFkSP65vvr9rQCr2JpRerNBoL4P6iaMf
Signature is valid
How to implement verify-offchain-signature functionality in a Solana contract？
